Utilizando JPA, a integridade do banco de dados só pode ser feita por meio das anotações @OneToOne, @ManyToOne etc?
Num banco de dados SQL a relação entre duas tabelas (1 para 1, por exemplo) garante a integridade por meio da Chave Primária e da Chave Estrangeira. Por exemplo, o exemplo Pessoa e Endereço. Se a chave estrangeira está na tabela Endereço, isso garante que um registro da tabela Endereço que faz referência a um registro da tabela Pessoa não seja deletado, por exemplo. Isso também é refletido no mapeamento com JPA através da anotação @OneToOne. Minha dúvida é se posso garantir essa integridade de outra forma, sem utilizar as anotações @OneToOne, @ManyToOne etc... Por exemplo, a classe Pessoa ficaria assim:
@Entity
public class Pessoa {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String nome;
   private String endereco;

   /* em vez de: 
   @OneToOne
   private Endereco endereco; */

   // getters e setters

}
E na classe de regra de negócio eu faria as validações para garantir essa integridade. Por exemplo, ao cadastrar um Endereço, devo cadastrá-lo para uma Pessoa que já exista no Banco de Dados. Essa validação já é garantida com o mapeamento através das anotações @OneToOne por exemplo, certo? Então, fazer as validações na regra de negócio para garantir a integridade dos relacionamentos é correto? Mesmo que eu esteja utilizando JPA que por padrão utiliza essas anotações? Estou com essa dúvida porque nunca vi algo do tipo, no entanto estou trabalhando em um projeto que é feita exatamente assim e é bastante funcional.

Você pode faze-lo, mas não posso te garantir que essa é a melhor solução para o problema.
A decisão de como será feito o mapeamento desse atributo depende muito da relevância dele no seu projeto.
Se formos levar para uma abordagem mais técnica, deixar o endereço como apenas uma String violaria a 1FN (primeira forma normal), que por sua vez diz que um dado de uma tabela deve ser atômico. No caso, o endereço possui mais de uma informação (nome da rua, número, estado, e as vezes até o CEP).
TLDR; É possível fazer o que você deseja, porém é importante lembrar que, como disse, não é uma abordagem usual e pode gerar refatorações/retrabalho a longo prazo. Porém, caso queira implementar, ao menos decomponha o atributo de endereço em outros "menores".
   @Entity
   public class Pessoa {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String nome;
// Sub partes de endereço
   private String rua;
   private String bairro;
   private String numero;
   private String cep;
   private String siglaEstado;
// private String pais; <-- Dependendo do escopo do projeto
}


Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.
